# Git pull error on Windows XP: Unable to determine absolute path of git directory

Tags: git, ssh, windows-xp, msysgit

I'm using Windows XP with git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0, Git Extensions and I'm using SSH to access remote repository.

When trying to do git pull, get below error:

```
C:\git-ssh\bin\git.exe pull --progress "origin" +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 309: pwd: -W: invalid option
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP]
Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
```

Problem occurs in Powershell and Git Bash and only in my machine.

Any ideas?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the WindowsXP a virtual machine running on XenServer?

If so, try uninstalling the XenTools

Comment: No. It's a Windows XP machine without virtualization